# How to load xml file in Marklogic with special character in element value?

Tags: xml, utf-8, special-characters, marklogic-9

I have a zip file which I loaded into the marklogic.zip file has many XML, and these XMLs have a special character in it. So while loading this xml out of zip file is throwing an error. How to handle this in MarkLogic?

Comment: Would be interesting to see which error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the XML need to comply to the XML standard, meaning you can't just wrap any kind of special character in XML.

If that is the case, your file should be in a particular encoding. MarkLogic by default assumes UTF-8, regardless of the xml processing-instruction. You can tell it to either attempt a full-repair, which will make it do a guess at the encoding by looking at the first few lines of XML (still ignores the xml-pi), or you pass in the accurate encoding yourself.

HTH!